# how to get upper bound of constrained integer in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am currently working on a project and I am unsure of how to get an upper bound of a constrained integer in Erlang.

Can someone please help me with this? Explain it to me.

I would really appreciate it, I tried looking online.

Comment: which constrain are you speaking of?

Comment: What's the difference between an upper bound for a constrained integer and an upper bound for an unconstrained integer?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive definition:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

high([X|Xs]) ->
    high(Xs, _Result=X).

high([X|Xs], Result) when X > Result ->
    high(Xs, X);
high([_|Xs], Result) ->
    high(Xs, Result);
high([], Result) ->
    Result.
```

In the shell:

```
12> c(a).                 
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

13> a:high([3, -11, 2, 11, 4]). 
11
```

Using a library function:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

high(Xs) ->
   lists:max(Xs).
```

In the shell:

```
21> c(a).                       
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

22> a:high([3, -11, 2, 11, 4]).
11
```